# Buffering on top of VFS

Tags: linux, filesystems, vfs

the problem I try to deal with it is the saving of big number (millions) of small files (up to 50KB), which are sent via network. The saving is done sequential: server receives a file or a dir (via network), it saves it on disk; the next one arrives, it's saved etc.
Apparently, the performance is not acceptable, if multiple server processes coexist (let's say I have 5 processes which all read from network and write at the same time), because the I/O scheduler doesn't manage to merge efficiently the I/O writes.

A suggested solution is to implement some sort of buffering: each server process should have a 50MB cache, in which it should write the current file, do a chdir etc; when the buffer is full, it should be synced to disk, therefore obtaining an I/O burst.

My questions to you:
1) I know that already exists a buffer mechanism (disk buffer); do you think that the above scenario is going to add some improvement? (the design is much more complicated and it's not easy to implement a simple test case)

2) do you have any suggestions, where to look if I would implement this?

Many thanks.

Comment: Do you have lots of RAM? If so, how about using tmpfs (/dev/shm)?

Comment: bTW: i think the VFS tag here is a bit missleading, even when it is technically a correct description and the internal name.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need to do better than

"apparently the performance is not acceptable".

Specifically

- How are you measuring it? Do you have an exact, reproducible figure
- What is your target?

In order to do optimisation, you need two things- a method of measuring it (a metric) and a target (so you know when to stop, or how useful or useless a particular technique is).

Without either, you're sunk, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

How important are those writes? I have three suggestions (which can be combined), but one of them is a lot of work, and one of them is less safe...

### Journaling

I'm guessing you're seeing some poor performance due in part to the [journaling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journaling_file_system) common to most modern Linux filesystems. The journaling causes barriers to be inserted into the IO queue when file metadata is written. You can try turning down the safety (and *maybe* turning up the speed) with `mount(8)` options `barrier=0` and `data=writeback`.

But if there is a crash, the journal might not be able to prevent a lengthy `fsck(8)`. And there's a chance the `fsck(8)` will wind up throwing away your data when fixing the problem. On the one hand, it's not a step to take lightly, on the other hand, back in the old days, we ran our `ext2` filesystems in `async` mode without a journal both ways in the snow and we liked it.

### IO Scheduler elevator

Another possibility is to swap the IO elevator; see `Documentation/block/switching-sched.txt` in the Linux kernel source tree. The short version is that `deadline`, `noop`, `as`, and `cfq` are available. `cfq` is the kernel default, and probably what your system is using. You can check:

```
$ cat /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler
noop deadline [cfq]
```

The most important parts from the file:

```
As of the Linux 2.6.10 kernel, it is now possible to change the
IO scheduler for a given block device on the fly (thus making it possible,
for instance, to set the CFQ scheduler for the system default, but
set a specific device to use the deadline or noop schedulers - which
can improve that device's throughput).

To set a specific scheduler, simply do this:

echo SCHEDNAME > /sys/block/DEV/queue/scheduler

where SCHEDNAME is the name of a defined IO scheduler, and DEV is the
device name (hda, hdb, sga, or whatever you happen to have).

The list of defined schedulers can be found by simply doing
a "cat /sys/block/DEV/queue/scheduler" - the list of valid names
will be displayed, with the currently selected scheduler in brackets:

# cat /sys/block/hda/queue/scheduler
noop deadline [cfq]
# echo deadline > /sys/block/hda/queue/scheduler
# cat /sys/block/hda/queue/scheduler
noop [deadline] cfq
```

Changing the scheduler might be worthwhile, but depending upon the barriers inserted into the queue by the journaling requirements, there might not be much reordering possible. Still, it is less likely to lose your data, so it might be the first step.

### Application changes

Another possibility is to drastically change your application to bundle files itself, and write fewer, larger, files to disk. I know it sounds strange, but (a) the iD development team packaged their maps, textures, objects, etc., into giant `zip` files that they would read into the program with a few system calls, unpack, and run with, because they found the performance much better than reading a few hundred or few thousand smaller files. Load times between levels was drastically shorter. (b) The Gnome desktop team and KDE desktop teams took different approaches to loading their icons and resource files: the KDE team packages their many small files into larger packages of some sort, and the Gnome team did not. The Gnome team had longer startup delays and were hoping the kernel could make some efforts to improve their startup time. The kernel team kept suggesting the fewer, larger, files approach.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I forgot to tell about the mount option, here they are: rw,noatime,nodiratime,nobarrier,logbufs=8,logbsize=256k,noquota. As you see, nobarrier is already set. The I/O scheduler: we're using deadline, but the tests with cfq showed no improvement. As for the big file (containers): because we're not doing only writes, but also deletions, we'll end up with large sparse files (unless we're doing some contraction of them, which will be costly in terms of processing); the idea using of large files seems to be the correct one, though, but there are too many changes to be done.

Comment: @Florin, wow, the easy options sound pretty well taken care of. Maybe SQLite3 would be the 'container' of choice? Compaction for free... :) Will the servers ever interact with their files? Or are they pretty much separate? Can you throw cheap new SSD drives at the problem? Modern SSD are fantastic at scatter-random reads and writes, and (maybe?) let you run with `noop` scheduler instead.

Comment: @sarnold  yes, the servers will interact often with the files; no SSD planned (too expensive).

Comment: @Florin, how much data are we talking? [$300 buys 120 gigs](http://eshop.macsales.com/shop/SSD/OWC/Mercury_Extreme_Pro_6G/), which would be enough for 2.2M 50KB files. Their literature claims _Random 4K file read/writes up to 60,000 IOPS_, which sounds bloody good to me. :) $300 USD! :) (Now I want one.)

Comment: @Florin, ah, then 120 gigs of SSD is a cute little drop in the bucket. :) Are any of the small files short-lived? (i.e., what percentage of the written files survives from one day to the next?) Could you do all your writes to SSD drives and migrate data to bulk storage over time?

Answer (score 0):

Creating/renaming a file, syncing it, having lots of files in a directory and having lots of files (with tail waste) are some of the slow operations in your scenario. However to avoid them it would only help to write lesser files (for example writing out archives, concatenated file or similiar). I would actually try a (limited) parallel async or sync approach. The IO scheduler and caches are typically quite good.